# Qual o significado e classificação gramatical de "vamos" em "vamos, responda à minha pergunta!"

Tags: verbos-defectivos, classe-gramatical

À primeira vista, "vamos" é o verbo "ir" conjugado na primeira pessoa do plural do presente do indicativo, do imperativo afirmativo ou do presente do subjuntivo. Neste caso, no entanto, **com o significado que tem na frase**, seria um verbo defectivo?  Poderíamos conjugá-lo em todas as pessoas desse tempo verbal?  **Mas não poderia também "vamos", isoladamente conforme no exemplo, ser uma interjeição?**

Comment: "Vamos" neste caso seria o verbo ir no imperativo (primeiro pessoa do plural), não no presente, pois é uma ordem. Porém, como é uma ordem para uma pessoa (você) e o locutor não participa, o correto no imperativo seria: "vai, responde a minha pergunta!". Sendo assim, acredito que "vamos" está sendo utilizado como interjeição. Do mesmo jeito que usamos quando torcemos para um time de um esporte qualquer ("vamos!" ou mais coloquial: "vamo!").

Comment: @PortuguêsAzul Concordo com a conclusão, mas a minha argumentação é diferente: mesmo em *vai, responde* eu interpreto *vai* como interjeição, porque *vai* não indica aí nenhuma ação a praticar nem é verbo auxiliar; limita-se a exprimir encorajamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A interpretação razoável deste *vamos* é como interjeição. As gramáticas aconselham no entanto o uso do ponto de exclamação: Vamos! [(Gramática Básica Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/gram/cap15-01-classificacao_das_interjeicoes).

[*Só Português*](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf89.php) explica que as interjeições «são uma espécie de **“palavra-frase”**, ou seja, há uma ideia expressa por uma palavra (ou um conjunto de palavras - locução interjetiva)», e ainda que «**interjeição** é a palavra invariável que exprime emoções, sensações, estados de espírito, ou que procura agir sobre o interlocutor, levando-o a adotar certo comportamento sem que, para isso, seja necessário fazer uso de estruturas linguísticas mais elaboradas». *Vamos* é classificada como interjeição de «animação ou estímulo» [nesta outra página do *Só Português*](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf90.php), e de «animação, encorajamento» na [*Infopédia*](http://www.infopedia.pt/$interjeicao).

E é assim que eu interpreto o nosso exemplo. Com *vamos*, o locutor procura agir sobre o interlocutor, reforçando a ordem para responder à pergunta. Com um contexto mais alargado ou entoação na comunicação oral, poderíamos precisar melhor o significado de *vamos*: poderia por exemplo exprimir impaciência e intimação ou solidariedade e encorajamento.

É claro que nós reconhecemos nesta interjeição o imperativo do verbo *ir*, e na sua origem estará o uso do verbo em expressões como *vamos embora* ou *vamos então esclarecer o assunto*, em que o verbo é igualmente usado para exortar. Mas nestas frases, *vamos* não é só um encorajamento: indica também, no segundo caso em conjunto com o verbo a que serve de auxiliar, a ação a praticar. No nosso exemplo *vamos* não indica qualquer ação a praticar: não está ligado a outro verbo a que possa servir de auxiliar (para isso teria que ser *vamos responder* ou *vamos respondendo*), nem indica qualquer ação descrita pelo verbo *ir*. É portanto puro encorajamento: uma interjeição.

Comment: clap, clap, clap.

Comment: @Centaurus Ah! «clap, clap, clap» é um locução interjetiva

Comment: Sim, também vejo "vamos" usado em todas essas situações: como encorajamento ("Vamos, Ronaldo, chuta! Chuta!  Goool) , intimação ("Vamos, responda a minha pergunta ou lhe meto bala na caixola"), de empatia e solidariedade ("Vamos, não fique triste.  Tudo vai se resolver") e vários outros significados.

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, e o que é fundamental é que é só uma expressão de encorajamento/intimação sem significar mais nada. Em «meus caros, vamos lá esclarecer isto tudo»,  também há uma expressão de encorajamento, mas neste caso *vamos* tem o sentido habitual do verbo, neste caso servindo de auxiliar a *esclarecer*, portanto não é interjeição.